# What is causing this logic error?

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, firebase

Here is my code and here is the output... I do not understand why my if statement above the log is allowing this to happen...This if statement that is nested inside of the for loop should not allow output whenever the fullname is the same the description...

```
    Firebase *firebase = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Recent", FIREBASE]];
    FQuery *query = [[firebase queryOrderedByChild:@"groupId"] queryEqualToValue:groupId];

[query observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    //Is group

    if ([snapshot.value[@"type"]  isEqual: @"group"]){
        self.title = snapshot.value[@"description"];
    }
    //Is individual
    else{

        NSString *senderId = snapshot.value[@"userId"];
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:PF_USER_CLASS_NAME];
        [query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:senderId];
        query.limit = 1;
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                // Do something with the found objects
                for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                    NSString *userName = [[PFUser currentUser]fullname];
                    if (object[@"fullname"] != userName){
                        self.title = object[@"fullname"];
                        NSLog(@"You're talking to: %@", object[@"fullname"]);
                        NSLog(@"Logged in user: %@", userName);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
        }];
    }



}];
```

Heres the log as well

```
2016-03-12 18:48:09.844 Gibr[34128:1436940] You're talking to: Testerten
2016-03-12 18:48:09.844 Gibr[34128:1436940] Logged in user: Travis Tubbs
2016-03-12 18:48:09.845 Gibr[34128:1436940] You're talking to: Travis Tubbs
2016-03-12 18:48:09.845 Gibr[34128:1436940] Logged in user: Travis Tubbs
```

Comment: What output do you _expect_? You've done a good job of showing the current situation, but in order to ask a question, you need to contrast that with the _desired_ situation.

Comment: It should only output if the fullname != userName. therefore I should not have any logged in Me and also outputting that I am talking to me...Because what I am doing is searching nodes and trying to return the node that is not mine, but the sender of a message.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you are using `!=` to compare two strings. But that's not what it's for; it's for comparing *objects*. The two string variables are not the same object; they are two different objects, two different variables.

If you want to know whether two string variables have the same value *as strings*, use `isEqualToString:`.

```
if (![object[@"fullname"] isEqualToString: userName])
```

Comment: That did it perfectly! I really appreciate the answer and fast response. I am new to Obj-c and there are little odds and ends that I do not know about yet. Thanks again.

Comment: Might help you to glance at my book, here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch10.html#_equality_and_comparison